# Массив постоянно начинает работать заново, что делать?

Tags: java, android

При нажатии на кнопку (btnNext) в `ImageView` должна меняться картинка, по сути, код то рабочий, но есть проблема. При нажатии на эту кнопку у меня пересоздается активити и поэтому массив начинает работать с самого начала. Есть ли решение этой проблемы?

```
Button btnNext = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
            final int[] images = {
                    R.drawable.p_reset,
                    R.drawable.pic,
            };
btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                    imageView.setImageResource(images[0]);

                }
            });
```

Comment: Зачем пересоздавать активити что бы поменять картинку?

Comment: @temq активити пересоздается с другой целью, чтобы поменять контент

Comment: @A.Schtolc, как я понимаю, вам надо чтобы сохранилась позиция в массиве после перзапуска активити? Т.е. если было 1 при завершении, то и после пересоздания должно быть 1?

Comment: @ЮрийСпб да, вы правы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть несколько вариантов того, как сохранить некие данные в активити так, чтобы при пересоздании они восстанавливались.

Если видоизменить ваш код, в коем вы не пересоздаёте активити, но перезапускаете, то нужное значение можно поместить в `Bundle` интента, коим вы активити перезапускаете. Т.е. как-то так:

```
finish();
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("KEY_POSITION", position);
intent.putExtras(b);
startActivity(intent);
```

После этого, когда так запущенная активити запустится, то вы сможете вытащить записанное значение так:

```
int position = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("KEY_POSITION");
```

А вообще, лучше сделать так:

1. Не перезапускать активити, а пересоздавать методом `recreate()`
2. Переопределить метод `onSaveInstanceState()` и в нём по аналогии с кодом выше сохранить значени епеременной `position`. Этот метод вызовется автоматически при пересоздании активити (например, при повороте экрана)
3. В метод `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` в виде аргумента придёт `Bundle` где и будет записанное в методе `onSaveInstanceState()` значение, кое вытаскивать по аналогии с кодом выше.

Comment: а вариант смены картинки после пересоздания активити возможен?

Comment: @A.Schtolc, конечно. На вскидку, можно, получив из Bundle значение генерировать случайное число до тех пор, пока оно не будет равно записанному. Так вы получите всегда новую картинку при пересоздании.